# How to create 3 dimensions matrix in numpy , like matlab a(:,:,:)

Tags: python, matlab, numpy

How to create 3 dimensions matrix in numpy , like matlab a(:,:,:) . I try to convert matlab code that create 3d matrix to python by use numpy.array and i don't know how to create 3d matrix/array in numpy

Answer (score 69):

```
a=np.empty((2,3,5))
```

creates a 2x3x5 array. (There is also np.zeros if you want the values initialized.)

You can also reshape existing arrays:

```
a=np.arange(30).reshape(2,3,5)
```

np.arange(30) creates a 1-d array with values from 0..29. The reshape() method returns an array containing the same data with a new shape.