# Create empty 3D numpy array and append it with each new given value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I feel like there has to be an easy solution to this, but I'm not too familiar with Numpy yet and couldn't find anything in the library fitting my needs. I feel like this is an obvious thing, but I couldn't find any similar question regarding this on StackOverflow.

Basically, I want to create a 3-dimensional **empty** array. I tried it like this: `matrix = np.array(None, ndmin=3)`. And now every time I have a new variable I want to append a dimension of the matrix I chose with the new value of the variable. How can I do that? I played around with `np.append()` and `np.insert()` but I couldn't come to a solution.

Comment: Don't try this.  Growing an array like this is slow. And as you found it is hard to initialize.  List append is better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Arrays have a fixed size. You can't append to them. If you know the upper bounds of the array, you can preallocate the array with

```
np.empty((10, 10, 10))
```

For a 10x10x10 matrix. You can then keep 3 indices x,y,z to track the actual size you have. Eg, add a new element with:

```
matrix[x,y,z] = newElement
x += 1
```

Then when you're done, you can extract the submatrix with

```
finalMatrix = matrix[:x,:y,:z]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use np.empty((x,y,z))

You can find a good explanation in this answer:
[How to create 3 dimensions matrix in numpy , like matlab a(:,:,:)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696135/how-to-create-3-dimensions-matrix-in-numpy-like-matlab-a)